# Where can I find medicine?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I know it is possible to be stung by bees in *Animal Crossing: New Leaf*.

I learned that the hard way when I was trying to find my furniture tree. Now, I have an eye swollen shut and all of my towns people are making fun of me. They're all being kind enough to inform me that I need **Medicine**, but they seem to be enjoying themselves at my expense too much to tell me where to actually *find* the **Medicine**.

**Where can i get medicine? I'd really like it if my townspeople stopped making fun of me.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Medicine is an item that can heal sick villagers and cure bee stings. One dose is available from the "[Nookling stores T&T Mart & Up](http://bidoofcrossing.tumblr.com/post/51874258260/animal-crossing-new-leaf-nookling-stores)"  every day for 400 Bells.
>
> If stung, there will be a hive shaped wound on the right section of the players eye. The sting can be hidden with sunglasses. Without the medicine, the sting will heal within a day. Medicine can be used to cure the sting; however, saving the game and restarting has exactly the same effect without the need to spend 400 Bells.
>   -http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Medicine

So, save -> quit -> reload and it should be gone is the easiest way.

Comment: I did a bit more research and found in New Leaf you go to the Nookling stores ranked T&T mart or higher. Information added to answer.

Answer (score 5):

I had a sting once and a villager saw my sting and gave me medicine! So if they make fun of you just ignore them and find the one that will offer you one.

Comment: If I remember right, Lolly gave me medicine after seeing my bee sting. But I think it could be any random villager.

Answer (score 4):

The ones that give you medicine are villagers with a new personality added in New Leaf. The female version is named "[Uchi](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Uchi)" and the male "[Smug](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Smug)". The villagers with these new personalities are kindhearted, and sort of act as an older sibling; they watch out for you and care for you. If you get to know them better and if they are of the opposite gender they will begin to flirt with you as well.

If you have one in your town go to them for free medicine if you get stung.

Answer (score 2):

well, I was in the same situation as you, then I spoke with Diva (that's the purple frog) and she gave me medicine! In fact, the 2nd time that happened she gave me medicine too! Though she also told me to "bee" more careful next time!

Comment: I used to have Diva in my town, but she left. It's probably because I accidentally reported her for using bad language. :'(

Comment: Actually, that does not relate to whether they move. The report for bad language resets their catchphrase and/or greeting to the default, unless it _is_ the default, in which case the catchphrase will change to "Uh-huh". I think the real reason is that you may have missed a "ping". A "ping" is when a villager spots you, uses the surprise emote (which makes a pinging sound, hence the name), and follows you doing a little dance. A "ping" may be to reward you or ask a dumb question, but in cases it may be them telling you that they want to move, which, if noticed, lets you reason with them.

Answer (score -2):

all you need to do is upgrade nookling junction then buy the medicine but the villager
 Rhonda gave me medicine